# Determine window height before content loading

Tags: jquery, navigation, window, height

I'm trying to make a left navigation fixed div, I want the div to be in the size of the windows height, problem is - the div loads content from mysql table so it changes every page load, and the jquery function that sets its height is fired after the page finishes loading.

Any solutions?
Thanks ahead.

Comment: I'm not understanding. You are supposed to change the height after page loads. So the div will always be the size of the window and be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to make the div `position:fixed` in your CSS.

Then use jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var w = $(window).height();
   $('#leftnav').css('height',w + 'px');
});
```

This is assuming a lot though. More info is always helpful.